# How does apache runs a application when a request comes in?

Tags: python, apache

I have a python web application running on apache2 deployed with mod_wsgi. The application has a thread continuously running. This thread is a ZeroMQ thread and listening to a port in loop. The application is not maintaining session. Now if I open the browser and sends a request to the apache server the data is accepted for the first time. Now when second time I send the request It shows Internal server error. When I checked the error log file for traceback, It shows the ZMQError:- The address already in use.

Does apache reloads the application on each request sent from the browser since so that the ZeroMQ thread is being created everytime and being assigned the port but since the port has already been assigned it shows error....

Comment: usually the ZeroMQ thread runs outside the context of the web server because of some of the reasons you have listed above,  Should it be running as its own service?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your application is using zmq to bind to some port.

As you have suspected already, each request can be run as independent process, thus competing in access to the port to bind to.

There can be so called workers, each running one process processing http/wsgi requests, and each trying to bind.

You shall redesign your app not to use bind, but connect, this will probably require having another process with zeromq serving something you do with that (but this last line is dependent on what you do in your app).